# What do I need to add to this code to allow me to draw road networks?

Tags: netlogo

```
globals[road?]

to go
if mouse-down?
  [ ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [ edit-world ] ]

end



to edit-world

if EDIT_TOOL = "Road" 
[
ask patches[set pcolor black]
]


if EDIT_TOOL ="Grass" 
[
  ask patches[set pcolor green ]
]


end
```

I want to be able to draw out a road network with this code. How would I specify the size of the patches and the shape of the patches I wish to draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a NetLogo world, all of the patches are always the same shape (square) and the same size (1 in NetLogo world units, and on the screen, however many pixels are in the model settings).

So the answer to "How would I specify the size of the patches and the shape of the patches I wish to draw?" is, you can't.

The code you have is almost right, but you need to remove the uses of `ask patches` in the `edit-world` procedure, and it should work. You already did `ask patch ... [ edit-world ]`, so `edit-world` is already a patch procedure, so it doesn't make sense to do `ask patches` again.

Comment: Thank you for you assistance on the previous matter. I now have a new problem where within my code should I place the set patch-size 10 and should I even use the commander "set"? Here is the code:

Comment: If my answer helped you, the best way to thank me is to accept my answer.  And if you want to ask something else, open a new question.